# What's the right cmake command to cross-compile for Raspberry Pi from M1 Mac?

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi, telegram-bot

My title seems general but I need to compile a project for my Raspberry Pi 3b. I want to use [Telegram's Bot API server](https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api) on it, but it takes *a lot* of time to compile, so I'm looking for faster ways to compile it. I heard about cross compiling, and I tried to compile the project from a Debian VM using UTM on my M1 Mac, but obviously arm64 isn't the same as armhf.

The main commands I need to perform are (from [the project's page, selecting `Debian 10+`](https://tdlib.github.io/telegram-bot-api/build.html?os=Linux)):

```sh
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=.. ..
cmake --build . --target install
```

from `build` folder.

I'm not an expert with compilation commands, and I've looked over a bunch of potential answer over the internet, but it's or too complicated, or not for `cmake`, or not for M1 Mac...

Anyway, I found what seems to be [a pretty decent solution](https://medium.com/@haraldfernengel/cross-compiling-c-c-from-macos-to-raspberry-pi-in-2-easy-steps-23f391a8c63), however once again it's for `clang++` and not `cmake`.

So my question is straightforward, **what `cmake` arguments/commands can I use to easily build the binary for my (slow) Raspberry from my (fast) M1 Mac?**

---

**EDIT 1:**
According to the answer of @sweenish, it's possible to pass directly arguments to the `cmake` command, which I did, wrapping them all into `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.
My current command is:

```sh
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=.. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot $HOME/sysroot -isysroot $HOME/sysroot -isystem $HOME/sysroot/usr/include/c++/10 -isystem $HOME/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/10 -L$HOME/sysroot/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10 -B$HOME/sysroot/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10 --gcc-toolchain=$(brew --prefix arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils)" ..
```

However, as the output shows, it seems like macOS/Xcode is natively appending 'default' arguments at the end of my command:

```sh
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot /Users/antoine/sysroot -isysroot /Users/antoine/sysroot -isystem /Users/antoine/sysroot/usr/include/c++/10 -isystem /Users/antoine/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/10 -L/Users/antoine/sysroot/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10 -B/Users/antoine/sysroot/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10 --gcc-toolchain=/opt/homebrew/opt/arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils  -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/cmTC_42ace.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_42ace
```

(notice the additional space after the end of *my* args and the beginning of uncontrolled args)

This leads to 3 main errors:

- `-L$HOME...` is not used
- `-arch arm64`, which I didn't choose to append, is unused too
- `Error: unable to disambiguate: -search_paths_first (did you mean --search_paths_first ?)`, again in the appended args

So to sum up, 'disabling' system args should solve 2/3 of my problems, and removing the `-L` one should be enough to be finally able to compile. How do I get rid of these final appended arguments?

---

Comment: I'm not super familiar with cmake, but you could pass the necessary flags in your first command: `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=""` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXXFLAGS.html#envvar:CXXFLAGS

Comment: You just need to understand that cmake is a build system that does the hard work of figuring out exactly how to put your project together. It generates a makefile and utilizes your build environment. On a Mac, your C++ compiler is clang++. So the instructions for clang++ can be directly applied to cmake.

Comment: Sweet, I'll try to copy-paste and adapt the args mentioned in the last section of the last link I provided

Comment: @sweenish I just tried and I got `CMake Error: Unknown argument --gcc-toolchain=/opt/homebrew/opt/arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils` while inserting all args of the article between `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` & `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`

Comment: You'll need to edit the question with that attempt and the actual error message.